# usb0 makes for an extremely slow boot

Tags: boot, networking, login, xubuntu

I got a brand new Lenovo Thinkpad T530 from my work recently, with xubuntu installed on it. It's extremely snappy, apart from booting. The moment it's slow (~2 minutes) is between entering my password in the login screen up until the point where my desktop comes up. I've been able to trace the problem to the existence of a `usb0` network interface, which is trying to come up.

If I run `sudo ifconfig usb0 down` before entering my password (through another screen), it shows my desktop almost immediately. Google doesn't make me any wiser as to how I should disable this `usb0` interface, but I'm pretty sure I won't use it and I'd like my laptop boot a bit faster.

Comment: Do you have anything plugged on the USB ports, besides keyboard and mouse? An android cellphone perhaps?

Comment: @ThiagoPonte Nope, not even a keyboard or mouse at the moment, the problem still persists.

Comment: See if there's any reference to usb0 in the file  ``/etc/network/interfaces``.

Comment: @ThiagoPonte Alas, there's no reference to usb0 in /etc/network/interfaces. So I'm guessing NetworkManager is the culprit here. Any clue ad to how I can disable usb0 (through /etc/network/interfaces, startup files, or otherwise)?

Comment: Some internal WWAN cards are recognised as USB devices. Do you have such a card installed? It is probably a driver or configuration error. Can you post the output of `lsusb` and `lspci`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting this into `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# Set up an interface which will not be allocated an IP address by
# ifupdown but will be configured through external programs. This
# can be useful to setup interfaces configured through other programs,
# like, for example, PPPOE scripts.
#
auto usb0
iface usb0 inet manual
      up ifconfig $IFACE 0.0.0.0 up
      up /usr/local/bin/myconfigscript
      down ifconfig $IFACE down
```

Note that this suggestion was taken from this [thread in ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1329983), i haven't tested it.